# No Keyboard on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: boot, usb, keyboard, raspberrypi, 19.10

I am trying to run Ubuntu 19.10 on Raspberry Pi 4 from the following link:

https://ubuntu.com/download/iot/raspberry-pi

I followed the instruction, but after booting, I cannot login to Ubuntu 19.10.
It seems that USB keyboard does not work on Raspberry Pi 4 and I cannot login.

Is any other versions of 64-bit Ubuntu available for Raspberry Pi 4?

Comment: It appears there is no USB power.

Answer (score 2):

I found these posts [1](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=121625) and [2](https://ubuntu.com/blog/roadmap-for-official-support-for-the-raspberry-pi-4)

Not sure if this applies to your case, but it seems to be that the USB port is not outputting enough current or you are running a Raspberry Pi4 w/ 4GB RAM

I'll quote from that post [1](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=121625) from here

---

Connect the Pi to the network by cable. The router has DHCP so it gets an IP address.
Look in the router to see what IP address the Pi receives.
From the PC establish an ssh connection as user pi to it:

```
ssh 192.168.0.106 -l pi
use password: raspberry
```

Open the file `/boot/config.txt` with nano texteditor as root

```
sudo nano /boot/config.txt
use password: raspberry
```

add the following line:

```
max_usb_current=1
```

to the end of the file

press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to save the file and exit nano

Shutdown and reboot the Pi with the command:

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Then, reboot, try the keyboard. It should now work.

Otherwise you may add instead the following line (following the same instructions above). This will implement a workaround for a kernel bug by limiting the memory to 3GB:

total_mem=3072

Comment: i had this issue. total_mem=3072 fixed it. why is that?

Comment: @alexandere Can you elaborate? You provided the last bit of the answer, thanks!

Comment: @FalcoGer There was some discussion on this on the github page.
https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/3093#issuecomment-520269280
I dont really understand this myself, but I believe its something to do with the amount of memory allocated.